# Uniform convergence and limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(E)<+\infty$.

Is it possible to find an example of a sequence $f_n$ converging uniformly to $f$ (with no assumption if they are non-negative, integrable) such that $\lim_n\int_Ef_nd\mu \neq \int_Efd\mu$? (maybe for $n, f_n,$ is non-negative and the integral can be $+\infty,$ for other $n,f_n$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and is not integrable so we can't define the integral)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E$, then
$$
\left| \int_E f_n \,d\mu - \int_E f \,d\mu \right| \leq \int_E |f_n - f| \,d\mu \leq \mu(E) \cdot \sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x) - f(x)|
$$
By definition of uniform convergence, the above sup tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That what I did, if $f_n$ are integrable, or if $f_n$ are all non-negative (the limit can be $+\infty$) what if, as mentioned, some of them are non-negative and other are not positive and not integrable?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then it forces $f_n$ to also be integrable for $n$ sufficiently large: $\int |f_n| d\mu \leq \int (|f| + 1) d\mu \leq \int |f| + \mu(E) < \infty$.  Nothing in this answer assumes anything about non-negativity of $f_n$ or $f$

Comment: We should not consider the case where they are non-negative?

Comment: You don't need to treat it as a separate case, the argument is the same either way

Comment: if they are non negative and not integrable, how can we write $\int f_n d\mu-\int f d\mu$? $(+\infty-\infty)$

Comment: If $f$ is not integrable, then the question is meaningless because you're asking if $/int f_n$ converges to $/int f$. So you need to assume $f$ is integrable before doing anything. Then as in my first comment, the uniform convergence forces the $f_n$ to also be integrable eventually. Again, whether or not anything is non-negative is totally irrelevant